# Reputation graph numbers are annoyingly close to round numbers

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, profile-page, reputation-graph

My rep graph shows numbers like 998 and 451. This annoys me so much - 998 is 2 off of 1000 / 1k and it isn't even clear what line the 998 refers to (the top of the grey segment or the bottom?).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My suggestion: Round to 1/100th of the rounded up number to 1sf:

Mine is 1,546. That rounds up to 2,000, and 1/100th is 20. Closest 20 is a reasonable number to round to.

Someone with 113,689 reputation would round to 100,000, and 1/100th is 1,000. So it would use steps of 1000.

---

Note that this is only the new graph in the new profile. The rep-tab graph is fine:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: As far as I can see it's only in the new mini graph in the profile page redesign, all others (old mini graph in reputation tab, network profile graph) appear to be fine, right?

Comment: @Sha yep, that's fine

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you had 1,545 when you took the picture/screenshot. Whoa! How did I get that?

I am going to guess that 998 is the median number between 451 and 998 + (998 - 451). Of course 451 is lowest rep at that date (month, day, year, decade, century, etc.). When you subtract 451 from 998, you get 547. Now add that to 998, which is 1545, or 1.5k when rounded to the hundredths place.

I will assume that 998 is just the middle number of 451 and possibly 1,545 (1.5k). You said that you had 1,546, one away from my estimate, which further proves my reasoning. I am not sure, I'll let the mods take care of this part.

About your feature request, I would agree. Just show the rep from the past seven days on the graph for the profile page and the steps would be determined by your average rep change or something like that. Just hopefully, the steps aren't too big or too small.

Comment: I had 1546, so yeah that seems to be it. I think 7 days is a little short, perhaps 1 month would be better.

Comment: I really don't mind. Just hoping the feature request is completed. :-)